# Transfer spatial data between databases using pgAdmin4

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm new to pgAdmin4 and performing tests before jumping in the deep end.

I've uploaded a large dataset into a the public schema within a database named 'spatial_db'. Rather than re-uploading the data to a new database through the DB Manager in QGIS, is there a way to transfer the spatial data in the public schema of the new database as shown below?

I'm conscious that moving the table alone, will only bring the attribute table across but perhaps I have this wrong, will it will bring the geometry across too?

[image]

Comment: Just a note; don't confuse what a database *client* is: an UI to access the database server. QGIS' *DB Manager* is one, as is *pgAdmin*. Moving data between databases has nothing to do with the client *per se* (I know QGIS offers *Drag'n'Drop* functionality, but behind the scenes it really executes a bunch of standard SQL statements). Usually, the safest way (keeping any relational structure of the source DB intact) for inter-DB transfers is to create a dump (`pg_dump[all]`) and restore it. For data-only transfers, there are plenty of more or less fit options, e.g. `db_link`, CSV export...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL query will do the trick, I think?

```
ALTER TABLE name
    SET SCHEMA new_schema
```

In my opinion, the `spatial_ref_sys` table must remain in the `public` schema.